# Find subsidiary by latitude and longitude (geolocation)

Tags: php, sql, geolocation

I'm looking for a **fast MySQL query** that returns the **nearest location** from a simple table:

Table: `locations`:

```
id |    city    |   latitude   |  longitude
-----------------------------------------------
1  |   Berlin   |   52.524268  |   13.406290
-----------------------------------------------
2  |   London   |   51.508129  |  -0.1280050    
-----------------------------------------------
3  |   Hamburg  |   53.551084  |   9.9936817
-----------------------------------------------
```

Client's coordinates ([latitude](/questions/tagged/latitude) + [longitude](/questions/tagged/longitude)):

```
$intLat = '52.370215700000000000'; // lat Amsterdam
$intLon = '4.895167899999933000';  // lon Amsterdam
```

Most provided examples @[SO](http://stackoverflow.com) are based on a *distance calculation*.

Even with coordinates from [**Birmingham**](http://www.distancesfrom.com/gb/Birmingham-latitude-longitude-Birmingham-latitude-Birmingham-longitude/LatLongHistory/12985.aspx), it returns `id=1` (Berlin).
The query should return London, because it is closer than Berlin. Shouldn't?

```
SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($intLat) ) 
                  * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
                  * cos( radians( longitude ) 
                  - radians($intLon) ) + sin(radians($intLat) ) 
                  * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM locations 
HAVING distance < 10 
   AND id IN(1,2,3) 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: You're going to need to ORDER BY the calculated distance ASC, so that the LIMIT picks the lowest distance result

Comment: @MarkBaker OMG I'm soo stupid...  Thank you !

Comment: stupidity is how we learn: we're so embarrassed by it, we never make the same mistake again :)

Comment: BTW:  If `distance` is not used elsewhere and `distance < 10` not needed, then `*3959` and `acos()` steps may be eliminated.  P.S.  Reverse then sort then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are selecting all locations with a radius of 10.

Then from that resultset you select 1 result at random with `LIMIT 1`.

You need to order by distance, so that the nearest locations is on top.
Like so:

```
SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($intLat) ) 
            * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
            * cos( radians( longitude ) 
            - radians($intLon) ) + sin(radians($intLat) ) 
            * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 

FROM locations 
HAVING distance < 10 
   AND id IN(1,2,3)
ORDER BY distance ASC  <<-- add this line
LIMIT 1;
```